# How can I select a cell by its content?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba

Is there a way - either manually or with [vba](/questions/tagged/vba)  - to select a cell with the input as its content?

Lets say I want to go over all the cells that have a content of `XX` (like find)
so I would do like in ruby something like cell('xx).select and it would take me that cell.

Can I do it programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to refer to a cell by content, then you have to name the cell (right click the cell, select define name). Then, when refer to definedName, it will display the content regardless of if the cell moves.

Comment: that works as well :)

Comment: also works is Cells.Find(What:="poptech", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate